# A question from Murdock's Pertubations: Theory and Methods.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the following two set of PDEs:

$$u_{0_{xx}}+u_{0_{yy}} = 0 , u_0|_{x^2+y^2=1}=1$$

$$u_{1_{xx}}+u_{1_{yy}} = u_0^2 , u_1|_{x^2+y^2=1}=0$$

For the first PDE I know that the solution is $u_0(x,y)=A \log (x^2+y^2) + 1$ for some constant $A$, but what is the solution of the second PDE how to solve this PDE?

Thanks.

Comment: Switch to polar coordinates? Your RHS in the inhomogeneous case has rotational symmetry, so you can probably assume that $u_1$ inherits this as well.

Comment: @Semiclassical I thought of polar coordinates already in the first PDE, but I don't know how to solve an inhomogenous Poisson PDE like this, what is the method here? Thanks.

Comment: Well, if it's rotationally symmetry like I claim, then it depends on $r$ alone and so it goes to just an ODE. That may still require some manipulation to solve, but it should be [weasel words] straightforward.

Comment: Also, are those the only boundary conditions? The first solution diverges at the origin, for instance, unless $A=0$. So it may be that you're making things harder than you need to...

Comment: @Semiclassical what's your experience with PDE?

Comment: In electromagnetism/physics, decent enough. In practical applications, though, I rely on Mathematica for solving BVPs.

Comment: @Semiclassical then how would you solve the PDE: $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=1$ with boundary condition $u|_{x^2+y^2=1}=0$?